# undefined reference to `XShmQueryVersion'

Tags: xorg, kde4, shm

I am try to compile a simple codebase that use simple X11 functions
but it gives error at compile:

```
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `XShmQueryVersion'
```

I used the `XShmQueryVersion` function in my code, I compiled it with

```
g++ myprogram.c -o program
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the compiler what libraries to find the X11 functions in.  The core X functions like `XOpenDisplay` are in *libX11*, while extensions are in additional libraries - like *libXext* for `XShmQueryVersion`.

The direct way to tell your compiler to link with these libraries is via `-l` flags:

```
g++ myprogram.c -o program -lXext -lX11
```

Once you get to building larger software, with Makefiles & such, there are tools to help manage the flags for these libraries, and you might have something in your Makefile such as:

```
CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags x11 xext`
LIBS += `pkg-config --libs x11 xext`
```